# how to save the editText values into an array or arrayList in a viewPager which extends PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have an activity which parses the json & sends its values to viewPager

```
    public class SwipeQuestions extends AppCompatActivity {

        // Declare Variables
        ViewPager viewPager;
        PagerAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_questions);  
         viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);                                                       

         viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
         adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SwipeQuestions.this, questions);
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);  
 }
}
```

& its XML(activity_swipe_questions) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

each question should appear in separate view with a editText where the user can enter the text & on the last question there will be a submit button which will save all the editText values in to an array or arrayList.
The Viewpager Adapter class is extending PagerAdapter is defined below

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Button submitButton;
    private ArrayList<String> enteredAnswerArray = new ArrayList<String>();                                            
    private ArrayList<String> questions;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> questions) {
        this.context = context;
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questions.size();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (object);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        TextView txtQuestion;
        EditText enteredAnswer;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,false);

        txtQuestion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);                                         // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        txtQuestion.setText(questions.get(position));                                               // Capture position and set to the TextViews

        submitButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        enteredAnswer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer_textbox);

        if(position == (questions.size()-1)){
            submitButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            submitButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println(enteredAnswerArray.size());

//                System.out.println("0"+enteredAnswerArray.get(0));
//                System.out.println("1"+enteredAnswerArray.get(1));

                Log.i("clicked",  "button izz clicked");
            }
        });

        (container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        (container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);                                            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager

    }

}
```

& its XML(viewpager_item) is defined below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/answer_textbox"
        android:text="Question" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer_textbox"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answer_textbox"
        android:text="Submit"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now for every question the user has entered some text in the editText fields & i want to save each editText value to an array or arrayList on click of submit button which is on the last view of viewPager.

Rite now i've 10 questions so i set viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit() to 10 so that the values entered by the user doesn't get deleted as user slides the screen

Can anyone help me out how the save the editText values in a viewPager.
I googled a lot But couldn't find anything relevant

Comment: Can anyone plz help me out in this...
i'm really struck @ this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to:

1. Create an *ArrayList enteredAnswers* in the ViewPagerAdapter class and add it's items in your instantiateItem method
2. Create a method that iterates the enteredAnswers list and returns a list of String with the written answers
3. Be careful to write all the necessary null checks

Comment: I've tried it @tsiogas.. i've declared 2 member variables private ArrayList<String> enteredAnswerArray = new ArrayList<String>(); EditText enteredAnswer; in viewPagerAdapter class & inside instantiateItem() enteredAnswer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer_textbox); enteredAnswerArray.add(enteredAnswer.getText().toString());

Comment: & onclick on submit button i'm logging the arraylist like this submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) { System.out.println(enteredAnswerArray.size()); for (String item: enteredAnswerArray){ Log.i("item: ", item);} Log.i("clicked", "button izz clicked");} }); but not is getting logged, eventhough its showing the arraylist size as 10

Comment: You need to create an ArrayList<EditText> and do editTextList.add(enteredAnswer) in the instantiateItem method.
Then create a method that iterates the editTextList like that:
foreach(EditText editText : editTextList){
    enteredAnswerArray.add(enteredAnswer.getText().toString()); 
}

I hope this will help you.